# combine source code from different files

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode

I am using Emacs Org-mode Babel source code block to write and use some small functions. Now I want to do a little bit more. Say after a while, I found the function I wrote in Org-babel is valuable for reuse, I want to put it into my personal python package, e.g., my_tools.

So org-babel provide extraction of the source code, lets say, I have the source code extracted into a file called `examples.py`, which has `func1` and `func2` in the file. I want to add these functions into a python file/module called `my_functions.py`, is there a python package or best practice to do such thing so the source code of `func1`, `func2` will be inserted into the module?

To me it is something I am trying to do for a while, usually, when working with python, we just write the code for one time usage, later on, we may find some code/functions are reused again and again, thus we want to save it to a package so that it can be easily installed and shared with others.

We can even add tags to the code so that when extract and insert it to the package module, it knows where to insert based on the tag information. I am little fuzzy here to know if there is already a PyPI package for such scenario, or how should I architect the package if I want to build such one for myself. I am not that experienced and would like to hear opinions on this.

Comment: This seems like a strange request. Why not just write your functions in a module to begin with?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think he's just talking about making a pip installable package, since that would answer his question. Once he creates and installs the package, he will be able to use its methods anywhere

Comment: @lordingtar Since I don't use Emacs Org-mode Babel, I am not entirely sure what OP wants. However, it seems to me that they want to programmatically "cut and paste" specific functions from separate source files into a new package module. "We can even add tags to the code so that when extract and insert it to the package module, it knows where to insert based on the tag information."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a big fan of keeping things simple. If I understand your requirements
correctly, your primary interest is in generating python source files and
modules rather than executing python code and having the results used in or
copied back into the org file.

If this is the case, I think your best approach is to just have an org file
which represents your /tools/ module. When you find a function etc which you
keep using in different files/projects and which should go into your tools
module, add that function code block into the org file representing your tools
module (along with appropriate docs etc). Then, update your other org files
which represent the different code blocks of your program to load that module
and reference that function.

In the org file which represents your tool module, you could use some of Org's
functionality to execute the code to incorporate tests etc. This way, you can
load your org file and have it execute the tests to varify all the utility
functions in your module are working.

In your other projects, just write your source blocks to source the functions
from your utility module. Don't worry about using org to try and do fancy
referencing or the like. Keep it simple. You can use org links to reference back
to your org file representing your toolbox modules to get documentation
references.

If on the other hand, you want to do something like a python lab book system,
where you run python code from within the org file and get results back which
you use for documentation or as input for other blocks, then you need to use
some of the advanced noweb features to handle more complex block references and
pass around arguments etc. You may also find the library of babel
useful.

> 14.6 Library of Babel
>       =====================
>
> ```
> The "Library of Babel" is a collection of code blocks.  Like a function
> library, these code blocks can be called from other Org files.  This
> collection is in a repository file in Org mode format in the `doc'
> directory of Org mode installation.  For remote code block evaluation
> syntax, *note Evaluating code blocks::.
>
>    For any user to add code to the library, first save the code in
> regular `src' code blocks of an Org file, and then load the Org file
> with `org-babel-lob-ingest', which is bound to `C-c C-v i'.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This should be doable using "tangling" of source code into files and `noweb` syntax to gather up individual pieces into a larger whole. The following is meant as an illustration of the method:

```
* Individual code blocks 

#+name: foo
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(princ "Hello")
#+END_SRC

and another one:

#+name: bar
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(princ "Goodbye")
#+END_SRC

* Combine them together

#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :tangle ./tangled/foo :noweb yes
(message "Package stuff")
<<foo>>
<<bar>>
#+END_SRC
```

Using `C-c C-v C-t` to tangle, gets you a file named `foo`, in the `./tangled` subdirectory (which has to exist already), whose contents are:

```
(message "Package stuff")
(princ "Hello")
(princ "Goodbye")
```

The pythonization of this should be straightforward, but the more advanced aspects of what you describe (using tags to select functions e.g.) are certainly not addressed by this (and I'm not sure how to do them off the top of my head).